# How to have 100% test coverage for function that calls invokeLater()?

Tags: swing, junit, jacoco, swingutilities

I am using Junit4.
This is my test class:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

public class UIUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testMultiline() {
        var multiLineText = "one\ntwo";
        UIUtil.showError(multiLineText, "title");
        assert true;
    }
}
```

I have the following Jacoco coverage result:
[image]

How can I test the lambda that Jacoco is complaining about in order to hit 100% coverage?

Comment: Make test wait for the option pane to pop

Answer (score 0):

Make test wait for dialog to pop. Having your implementation you can simply add another task to the EDT queue and wait for it to finish.

```
@Test
public void testMultiline() throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
    String multiLineText = "one\ntwo";
    UIUtil.showError(multiLineText, "title");
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
       //just wait, nothing more
    });
    assert true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the same result unfortunately. Were you able to get a different result on your side?